# How do I combine firebase authentication and realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, arduino, esp32

I am building a simple project that uses the esp32 to collect sensor data and then save it to a Realtime Database on Firebase, I then retrieve the data in Android Studio to show to the user.

My problem is that my app's authentication works fine and logs in as expected and I can also create new users. But my ESP data is stored in the Realtime Database. How do I combine the authentication and the Realtime Database so each user has his own data?

I need a table something like this for each user that registered.
**User**
*-ESP32*
-Sensor1
-Data
-Data
-Sensor2
-Data
-Data
-Sensor3
-Data
-Data

Or do I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I combine the authentication and the Realtime Database so each user has his own data?

If you have successfully implemented Firebase Authentication, then what remains to be done, is to create the Realtime Database schema. That being said, the simplest schema I can think of might look like this:

```
db
|
--- users
     |
     --- $uid
          |
          --- sensors
               |
               --- $sensorId
               |     |
               |     --- //data
               |     |
               |     --- //data
               |
               --- $sensorId
                     |
                     --- //data
                     |
                     --- //data
```

In this way, you'll be able to create a reference that points to the authenticated user and read all the corresponding data. One important to remember, is to always secure your data using [Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Comment: Hey Hansie. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you for the answer I am still trying to figure out how to create this database schema so that one user can only have access to his own esp32 and the data these esp's send to the Real time Database